# Login to reddit using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to reddit.com using selenium python.

Username field is filled properly but the password field is not filled right. My password is 10 digits long but in the password field of reddit, it is only filling 8 digits.

I don't know what's wrong. Help is appreciated.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

# Firefox 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://reddit.com/')

text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='login_login-main']/input[2]")
text.clear()
text.send_keys('')#username

passwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='login_login-main']/input[3]")
passwd.clear()
passwd.send_keys('')#password

time.sleep(3)

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='login_login-main']/button[@class='btn']")
button.click()

# Close the browser!
# driver.quit()
```

Comment: Works for me - it shows the 10 "starts" when I send 10 keys.

Comment: are you able to login ?. I am using firefox 38, can this be a part of the problem ?

Comment: And, yes, firefox 38 is not compatible even with the latest selenium 2.45. Downgrade firefox to 35.0.1 to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no problems with the password field.

You are locating the "login" button incorrectly, the button is not directly inside the form, replace:

```
//form[@id='login_login-main']/button[@class='btn']
```

with (watch the double slash):

```
//form[@id='login_login-main']//button[@class='btn']
```

---

Note that a more reliable approach here would be to, first, find the `form`, then locate the inputs "by name", and the submit button "by text":

```
form = driver.find_element_by_id("login_login-main")

username = form.find_element_by_name("user")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("username")

password = form.find_element_by_name("passwd")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("password")

submit = form.find_element_by_xpath("//button[. = 'login']")
submit.click()
```

Comment: thanks alecxe, Yes turns out I was locating the login incorrectly. 
But as I see it, isn't 'login' a child of 'form' ?. I am fairly new to web languages, so pardon me if I am asking an obvious.

**Bug**: It's very strange though. My password was *****@\***. It used to fill upto *****@\* here. But when I changed my password to 'password' or 'a1234567890', it worked.

I don't know what happened. Any idea?

Comment: @paramvir interesting, I'm guessing this is either a compatibility issue (see my comment above), or might be related to the active keyboard, make sure you have english US turned on (wild guess, yeah).